# Stop Deformation on Bezier Curves

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

Real curve noob here.

I'm building fan blades. I have an extruded cube and a BezierCircle. I just want to place copies of the object around the curve. But when I do wire up the object and curve It completely deforms the shape of the object rather than just position copies around the curve.

I end up with this:

[image]

How can I stop the curve altering the shape? Or am I just getting the entire approach wrong. Very confused.

Comment: @Duarte I think that answer needs updating for 2.8, I just ended up Googling again but thanks anyway, it's more or less the same and got me on the right track. I found the answer here https://www.versluis.com/2019/07/duplicating-an-object-along-a-path-in-blender-2-8/

Comment: Actually, scratch that. The method in that article no longer works as described either. Sheesh, why is this so hard?

Comment: Anyone finding this there is a goo thread here that helped but I'm still not happy with the results I'm getting. This seems like a really clunky solution to me.

https://blenderartists.org/t/b2-8-where-is-duplication-panel-dupliframes-gone/1153070/19

Comment: Dupliframes doesn't exist anymore in 2.8, you need to use Duplifaces for example. For your object you could simply use Array modifier with an Offset Object, check this solution!!

Comment: Actually it seems Duplefaces is now called Instancing and the option is "Faces".

Comment: yes exactly, but for your fan blades you could as well try Array with Offset Object